# Google Drive files list using PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP and the Google Drive API and need to get files and folder list.
I want to list out all files in my Google Drive in my web page.

My code is :

```
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
    define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
    $client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT_URI');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    //Request authorization
    print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
    print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for access token
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    retrieveAllFiles($service);

    //foreach($file as $result){
    //  echo $file;
    //}

    function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
    $result = array();
    $pageToken = NULL;

    do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
    } while ($pageToken);

    foreach($files->items as $item)
    {
        echo $item['title'];
    }
    }
```

How can I get list of file ? 
Please help me....
Give me some example code to retrieve all files...

Comment: What do you see when you run this script? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on [Files:list docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) that contain a working sample with pagination.
You can either use the [DrEdit sample](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit) Google Drive app in a bunch of languages.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.